# PCB Design position of flyback diode for motor

Tags: motor, diodes, flyback

I have a simple question:

If I design a PCB, does it physically matter at what position my flyback diode for my motor is? Does it matter if it's "in front" of my MOSFET or not?

I made two examples to demonstrate my question:

Example 1:
[image]

Example 2:
[image]

Is example 1 equal to example 2?

Comment: If the tracks were thin and the distance between the diode and the MOSFET was large (a couple of centimeters) then I would prefer example 1 and have the diode as close to the motor connections as possible. But your example uses short and wide tracks so I do not expect there to be any noticeable difference. So either solution is OK.

Comment: It's an interesting theoretical question. The flyback current will generate a magnetic field, but also distinctly different right at the pn junction where long range electron effects are instead randomized. These fields themselves may reach the fet or may also create non-coulomb electric fields that affect it. I suspect it's minor. But it would be interesting to design an experiment to test predictions, once made. Would require money and time to see. Would love to see the results, though. I could be wrong and it's not minor. If so, someone will respond and say so. Either way I learn.

Answer (score 11):

> *does it physically matter at what position my flyback diode for my
> motor is ?*

Ideally, the diode should be as close to the motor as possible in order to minimize the circuit-loop in which the flyback current flows. This is to reduce, as far as is possible, EMI into other circuits.

Other than that, there are no special considerations unless you were designing a motor interface to something that was intended to be used in a flammable gas area (unlikely of course but I need to mention it).